# Applying Complex transformation in configurable manner using scala function and spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to implement complex transformation in a configurable manner .
I receive data in file say csv, avro etc which will remain same and through this I will make a dataframe
Now I need to write different function having different transformation logic. using spark scala which will be applied on dataframe .
Based on parameter we pass using config file , particular function will get executed with required transformation

The parameter which we will pass through configuration that will pick the respective function
Any input to implement this please

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `transform` function in spark.

Start by defining the functions to perform transformations.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def addOne(df: DataFrame) = {
  df.withColumn("plusOne", df("col") + 1)
}

def addTwo(df: DataFrame) = {
  df.withColumn("plusTwo", df("col") + 2)
}
```

Then define a test dataframe

```scala
val test = (1 to 10).toDF("col")
test.show(3, false)

/* outputs:

+---+
|col|
+---+
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
+---+
*/
```

Then use the `transform function to make actual transformations based on your parameter in config.

```scala
val parameter = 1
val result1 = parameter match {
  case 1 => test.transform(addOne)
  case 2 => test.transform(addTwo)
}

result1.show(3, false)

/*
+---+-------+
|col|plusOne|
+---+-------+
|1  |2      |
|2  |3      |
|3  |4      |
+---+-------+
*/
```

In the case of `parameter` being a different value you can see how it would behave below.

```scala
val parameter = 2

// below code can be extracted into a function
val result2 = parameter match {
  case 1 => test.transform(addOne)
  case 2 => test.transform(addTwo)
}

result2.show(3, false)

/*
Outputs:

+---+-------+
|col|plusTwo|
+---+-------+
|1  |3      |
|2  |4      |
|3  |5      |
+---+-------+

*/
```